# C++ template class inside templated class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, delegates

I'm trying to create a Delegate class that will act similarly to the C# one.

My goal is the following.

```cpp
void say() { std::cout << "Hello, World!\n" << std::endl; }
int add(int n) { return n + 1; }

[...]

Delegate<void> s(say);
s();
Delegate<int, int> * a = new Delegate<int, int>(add);
```

I'm pretty close to a result that can handle both normal C function functions and C++ methods (by the way, I'm assuming C++11 standard). Here's what I've came to.

```cpp
template <class R, class ...P> class Delegate
{
    public:
        template <class F, class T> Delegate(F method, T& object)
            : handler(MethodDelegate<T, R, P...>(method, object))
        {}

        template <class T> Delegate(T function)
            : handler(FunctionDelegate<R, P...>(function))
        {}

        virtual ~Delegate() noexcept {}

        virtual R run(P... args) const = 0;
        inline R operator()(P... args) const
        {
            return this->run(args...);
        }

    private:
        template <class _T, class _R, class ..._P> class MethodDelegate : public Delegate<_R, _P...>
        {
            public:
                MethodDelegate(_R (_T::*method) (_P...), _T& object)
                    : object(object), method(method)
                {}
                virtual ~MethodDelegate() noexcept {}

                _R run(_P... args) const
                {
                    return (object.*method)(args...);
                }

            private:
                _T& object;
                _R (_T::*method) (_P...);
        };

        template <class _R, class ..._P> class FunctionDelegate : public Delegate<_R, _P...>
        {
            public:
                FunctionDelegate(_R (*function) (_P...))
                    : function(function)
                {}
                virtual ~FunctionDelegate() noexcept {}

                _R run(_P... args) const
                {
                    return (*function)(args...);
                }

            private:
                _R (*function) (_P...);
        };

        Delegate<R, P...> handler;
};
```

It compiles with `clang++ delegate.cpp --std=c++11` and `g++ delegate.cpp --std=c++11` but the problem comes when I try to edit the `main`:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Delegate<void> s(say);
    s();
}
```

Clang++ says:

```
delegate4.cpp:73:21: error: field has incomplete type 'Delegate<void>'
            Delegate<R, P...> handler;
                              ^
delegate4.cpp:109:17: note: in instantiation of template class 'Delegate<void>' requested here
    Delegate<void> s(say);
                   ^
delegate4.cpp:18:38: note: definition of 'Delegate<void>' is not complete until the closing '}'
template <class R, class ...P> class Delegate : public Object
                                     ^
1 error generated.
```

I guess I need to move the implementation of `FunctionMethod` and `DelegateMethod` classes outside (like I'd do with normal methods when splitting `.h` headers and `.cpp` codes) but I might be wrong.

Can someone help me please?
If possible, I'd like not to modify the desing/inheritance pattern and with no external functions (that's why I used the constructors trick base on C++ template function "auto-guessing").

Thank for your patience and help and sorry for the long post.

## Edit

As @chris pointed out in the comments, I'm trying to use a "raw object" of the same type of the class. A possible solution would be to use pointers, but this would require dynamic allocation I guess. Is there a way to do so *without* dynamic allocation?
Moreover, does anyone knows how to do a third class called `LambdaDelegate` that keeps the sape hierarchy? Thank you :)

Comment: This problem is the same one as `struct S {S s;};`.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you are trying to reinvent `std::function`. Your very first example - your supposed goal - compiles after adding `template <typename R, typename ... Args> using Delegate = std::function<R(Args...)>;` [Live example](http://rextester.com/MZH11604)

Comment: @chris You're absolutely right, I feel so stupid, but thanks for pointing it out, I'm join to update the question and see if there's a way for preventing dynamic allocation.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik You're right, but I was just trying to do it by myself, just for research purposes, then I heard bad feedbacks on std::bind and std::function... I'm going to update the question.

Comment: A lambda object can be arbitrarily large (it may have captured arbitrary number of arbitrary objects by value). A particular instance of `LambdaDelegate<R, Args...>` would of course have some fixed size. Naturally, there's no way for an object of size `N` to own a copy of another object of size `M > N` without some form of dynamic allocation.

Comment: You want an abstract class, say `DelegateImpl`, with virtual `run` method. `MethodDelegate`, `FunctionDelegate` and so on would derive from that class. `Delegate` constructor would create an appropriate instance of the derived class, and hold on to it by `DelegateImpl*`. To avoid heap allocation, you can implement a small object optimization. Reserve some space (via `std::aligned_storage`) inside `Delegate` object. Construct sufficiently small `XDelegate` instances in that storage via placement new, and larger ones on the heap. `MethodDelegate` and `FunctionDelegate` are all the same size.

Comment: Of course, these are precisely the techniques that a typical `std::function` implementation uses. So, again, all you are doing is reinventing that.